# Load device at boot

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox

I am working on a command line/raw Arch distro. Usually, I load shared with the host storage unit with

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf myDevice /home/myName/myDevice
```

I found this [reference](http://wideaperture.net/blog/?p=4034) really useful in this sense. Now am trying to mount the device automatically at boot time, but without success. What is the correct procedure to do that?

Comment: Entries are normally placed in /etc/fstab to allow them to mount at boot time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new entry for your mount point in `/etc/fstab`.

```
# <file system> <mount point>           <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
myDevice        /home/myName/myDevice   vboxfs  defaults        0       0
```

The format is documented in [fstab man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/fstab.5.html). Usage is also extensively explained in [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab).